# Constructing logical sentences that involve negative integers over the nonnegative integers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Consider the following statement:

> If $x$ and $y$ are integers and $x^5 = y^7$, then $y$ is at most $x$.

I'd like to build a sentence for this statement in the model of $(\mathbb{N}, +, \times)$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of nonnegative integers and $+$ is just the relation (where here I define a relation as a mapping from tuples of *nonnegative* integers to a boolean value): $\{(a,b,c): a + b = c\}$ and $\times$ is the relation $\{(a,b,c): a \times b = c\}$. By "sentence", I mean a logical formula with no free variables.

How can I write the above highlighted statement in terms of the given model if variables in this model can only take only take on nonnegative integers? It seems to me that since any relation I can derive from the '$+$' can only involve tuples of nonnegative integers, it is impossible to define negative integers in terms of the model. I'm wondering if instead I should construct a sentence for the following statement

> If $x$ and $y$ are *nonnegative* integers and $x^5 = y^7$, then $y$ is at most $x$.

But I'm not sure if these two highlighted statements are logically equivalent.

As an example, suppose I want to construct a sentence for the following statement in the model $(\mathbb{N}, +, \times)$:

> Infinitely many prime numbers exist

The corresponding sentence would be

> $\forall q \exists p \forall x \forall y[p > q \land ((x > 1 \land y > 1) \implies xy \neq p)]$

We can easily define the relations $<$ and $\neq$ in terms of the $+$ and $\times$ relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to formally define arbitrary integers in terms of nonnegative integers.  For instance, you could choose to represent an integer by an equivalence class of pairs $(a,b)$ (which you think of as representing $a-b$) under the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ if $a+d=b+c$.  So every time you want to talk about an integer, you can talk about two natural numbers, and every time you want to say two integers are equal you should instead refer to this relation $\sim$.  You can define addition and multiplication of integers as well: $(a,b)+(c,d)$ can be represented as $(a+c,b+d)$ (since $(a-b)+(c-d)=(a+c)-(b+d)$) and $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)$ can be represented as $(ac+bd,ad+bc)$ (since $(a-b)(c-d)=(ac+bd)-(ad+bc)$).  You can also define the ordering of the integers by $(a,b)<(c,d)$ iff $a+d<b+c$ (since $a-b<c-d$ iff $a+d<b+c$).

So as a simple example, if you wanted to express the statement $$\text{For every integer $n$ there exist integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $k\ell=n$}$$ in the structure $(\mathbb{N},+,\times)$ you could do so as follows: $$\forall a\forall b\exists c\exists d\exists e\exists f[cf+de+b=a+ce+df]$$
Here $(a,b)$ represents $n$, $(c,d)$ represents $k$, and $(e,f)$ represents $\ell$, so $(cf+de,ce+df)$ represents $k\ell$.  You can use the same idea to express your statement involving $x^5$ and $y^7$ (but it will be pretty complicated since in representing $x^5$ and $y^7$ you will essentially be expanding out $(a-b)^5$ and $(c-d)^7$ completely).

In the language of model theory, we say that we can [*interpret*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)) the structure $(\mathbb{Z},+,\times,<)$ in the structure $(\mathbb{N},+,\times)$.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: the edited OP makes this answer obsolete; Eric's is the correct one. However, I'm going to leave this up since I think it helps illustrate some of the subtleties around questions like this one.*

What do you mean by "construct a sentence for the statement ..."?

The simplest interpretation is that - given a statement $\sigma$ in English - you want a sentence (=wff with no free variables) $p$ such that $p$ is true in $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ iff $\sigma$ is true. Well, then this is easy: just determine whether $\sigma$ is true, and then if $\sigma$ *is* true, let $p$ be "$\forall x(x=x)$," and if $\sigma$ is *false*, let $p$ be "$\exists x(x\not=x)$". Then $p$ is true in $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ iff $\sigma$ is true!

Presumably you find that unsatisfying. Well, then you need to clarify what exactly you mean by "construct a sentence for the statement . . .". I'm not just nitpicking - this ambiguity gets in the way of giving your question a meaningful answer.

Incidentally, it's worth noting that exponentiation isn't even definable using addition alone, so in a precise sense there *can't be* a non-"cheating" answer.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. The OP is given the statement in block quotes in the question's body. That statement is a mix of natural language and symbols and the OP is required to formalize it in the language that contains $(\mathbb N, +), x, y,$ etc.

Comment: @Noah Schweber By "build a sentence for this statement in the model...", I just mean converting it into a well-formed formula over the alphabet of $\{\land, \lor, \neg, (, ), \forall, \exists, x, +\}$ (where $x$ here is a variable, but we can use as many distinct variables as we please) such that this formula has no free variables. I'm also not concerned whether the statement itself is true or false.

Comment: You need to supply some more context. Your question as it stands is incoherent: the highlighted statements involve free variables $x$ and $y$, so it is unclear what you could mean by a "sentence for this statement". (You will also have considerably difficulty talking about $x^5$ and $y^7$ in the structure (\Bbb{N}, +)$).

Comment: The criterion would be that if we convert the desired well-formed formula into plain english, we would obtain the first highlighted statement.

Comment: I'll try add an example to my question.

Comment: @GitGud You're missing my point. What does "formalize it in" mean, exactly? A sentence is either true or false, so it can be formalized in *any* language as either "$\exists x(x\not=x)$" (if false) or "$\forall x(x=x)$" (if true). My point is that the OP needs to clarify exactly what they mean.

Comment: @simplex495: the highlighted statements are assertions about two mathematical objects $x$ and $y$: these mathematical objects will have to be free variables in the logical formulas that formalise those statements. However, your question is very specific that those formulas should be sentences, i.e, that they should not have free variables. You really do need to clarify the question.

Comment: @RobArthan I interpreted the highlighted paragraphs as being in the scope of implicit universal quantifiers. Of course you're right though, the OP definitely needs to clarify (and frankly I'm having trouble seeing a meaningful question here).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: my comments were intended to be about the question and not your answer, but the comment trail led me astray.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed I had missed your point. However, the exercise of modelling statements in a formal language is a typical one. That the statement, once formalized, might be equivalent to either $\exists x(x\neq x)$ or its negation is avoiding the issue.

Comment: @GitGud " ... is avoiding the issue." In general I'd agree, but in this case no, it's not - it's in fact a huge issue here, since the language of addition alone **has no way to express exponentiation** (or even multiplication)! So there is *no way* to solve the problem in the "intuitive" way, hence *any* solution has to make use of technicalities.

Comment: Oh boy, I made a dumb mistake, sorry Noah. $\times$ should be permitted, let me fix that.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK, fair enough. I'd expect your last comment to be part of the answer, though.

Comment: @GitGud It is - last paragraph . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is now, it was when I implied it wasn't. But it wasn't in the first couple of versions of the answer. The edits weren't visible on my screen. **Edit:** There were horrendous, misleading typos in the first version of this comment. They are now fixed.